# PyQT Application Hangs when UI is Closed

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I'm currently having trouble when trying to close my application. As of now, my application currently spawns and thread that runs in a while loop (while True loop), while my main thread initializes and runs the UI in PyQT.

```
def main():

    group_size = 8 
    buffer_size = 4 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dgui = DirectGui(group_size, buffer_size)
    engine = KCluster_Engine(group_size, buffer_size)
    dgui.set_engine_ref(engine)
    engine.assign_interface(dgui)
    thread = Thread(target = engine.start)
    thread.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I close out of my main window of my application in PyQT, the command that spawned the python script in the shell cannot be stopped, even with a ctrl-c.

What is the best way to deal with this behavior? When I close my application, I also want the spawned thread to stop, join and quit this process. How do I do this?

Comment: most probably that thread is stuck somewhere. put logs there and see whats happening

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I know for a fact its spinning on a while True loop. Is there anyway to call it to stop after quitting the application?

Comment: does `app.exec_()` returns when you close last window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Python Standard Library, you have two ways of killing your thread :

- either you make it daemonic (`thread.daemaon = True`) and it will be killed without any possibility of proper cleaning
- or you use a signaling method like `Event` that you test in appropriate places in you thread

But I think you should have a look to this older (but still of actuality ...) question in SO : [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

All this supposes that `app.exec_()` returns properly in your main thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the thread daemonic it's going to stop after you exit the application.
Put `thread.daemon = True` before starting it (if you do it after calling start an exception will be raised). It should work fine with threads from the threading module.